# django filter with icontains doesn't work

Tags: python, django

hey guys i try to execute this query with icontains condition

```
User.objects.filter(email__icontains='something')
```

the situation here is the email field is a custom field, this class storage the encrypt value in the database, and decrypt the value again when i need call the object

```
class AESEncryptedField(models.TextField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            return cryptography.encrypt(value)
        else:
            return None

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        try:
            return cryptography.decrypt(
                super(AESEncryptedField, self).to_python(value)
            )
        except TypeError:
            """
            Field isnt encrypted on the database, but it will be
            on the first model.save()
            """
            return super(AESEncryptedField, self).to_python(value)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'max_length': self.max_length, 'widget': forms.TextInput}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(AESEncryptedField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

and here is the model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = AESEncryptedField(
        verbose_name='correo',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
```

when execute this query works fine

```
User.objects.filter(email='something@example.com')
```

but when use email__icontains condition doesn't work, the result is empty.

Someone knows if a need override some method?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you read this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871006/django-filters-and-django-encrypted-fields